# Disable split view using Swift UI on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui

Is there a way to disable the SplitView using SwiftUI on iPad inside a navigation view?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By setting the `NavigationViewStyle`

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView(), label: {Text("TestView")})
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct NavView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavView()
    }
}
```